# Retrieving user email address from Google Form survey results

Tags: google-workspace, google-forms

I am a Google Apps user.

Is there a mechanism or script which allows me to retrieve the respondents email address from a survey?

I can see the timestamp but there is no respondents email field.

Please try and break this into layman's term as I have not really scripted.

Comment: I thought there is a getRespondentEmail() Is it possible not to use this to pull the data using a script ?

Comment: Following up on the suggestion given by @OlleMuronde -- here is a script by Bharati that might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/a/23151745/445686

Answer (score 3):

NOTE:

Google Forms and the below referred help article were updated.

1. For Google Workspace accounts, a form could be set to automatically log the email address of the user from the same organization as the form owner
2. For common Google accounts the Collect email addresses option adds a question that allow the respondent to type an email address

---

Original answer:

From [View and manage form responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en)

> Record the email addresses from people who fill out your form. When
> someone takes your survey, they will be required to enter their email
> address before they submit the form.
>
> If you use a Google account through work or school, respondents will
> see a message at the top explaining that their username will be
> collected automatically.
>
> 1. Open a form in [Google Forms](https://forms.google.com/).
> 2. In the top right, click Settings [image: Settings].
> 3. Check the box next to "Collect email address."

Comment: @PGSystemTester: Added a note.

Comment: Cool, I actually didn't know that about the Work Account. You might modify the wording: *For common Google accounts the Collect email addresses option adds a question that allow the respondent to type an email address, which will be displayed in results. Note this is not the authenticated google account address which is not visible to the form admin.*

I discussed in more detail with an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150226/how-to-get-read-email-id-from-a-from-response/66751044#66751044