# Can we use signed in email address of the user to auto fill the email text box in Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am creating a Google Form in which people will enter their names and email address and other details. I have done this previously but have noticed that most of the people uses their wrong email address. I want to create a google form which will have name and email address. I will share the link of the form to users.

Users will have to first sign in to their Gmail account and then they will be redirected to Google Form in which I want that the email text box should be automatically filled and should not editable.

For eg., `john27@gmail.com` has signed in and opened the Google Form. So the email text box in form should automatically fill up with `john27@gmail.com` and should be non editable so that user cannot edit and we capture the users valid email address.

Can anyone please tell me if this is possible and how we can achieve it. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This is a feature only for Google Workspace account for users from the same domain. Related [Google form anonymity in organization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126459/88163)

Comment: Related [Retrieving user email address from Google Form survey results](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80292/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the cog wheel next to the SEND button. There will be an option to collect email addresses. This will populate an email field in the CSV file for you to view. You can view the CSV file by going to responses and selecting the Google Sheets Icon and selecting create new file ( or you can link an already existing file).

EDIT: You don't need to create a field for emails if you select "collect email addresses". The user is notified when they open the form that their email is being collected and is displayed as its own box at the top.